# Fix CVE-2017-5487 vulnerability

Tags: security

I have a website which is running Wordpress 6.4.2. Today I received a warning from the hosting service that my website is affected by the CVE-2017-5487 vulnerability, and that I have to do something to fix this. I have no idea what that is, a quick Google search suggested to upgrade to Wordpress 4.7.1 or later, but I already have 6.4.2. What can I try?

Comment: Have you asked your host? Are you sure you don’t have an old install somewhere in your account?

Comment: Yes, I asked. Their solution is to put the whole website behind a password protected thing, but this is not good for me because now only people with an account in such system will be able to read, and I use it with students who have no credentials. Also, I am very sure there are no old installations.

Comment: Ask them to point you at the specific vulnerability then. If it's from a vulnerability scanner it should give you the file path it's found so you can investigate. You could also look for an exploit script for the CVE to test against your website so you can prove to them you're not impacted.